# Access fingerprint scanner on Galaxy S5

Tags: java, android, fingerprint

I am trying to learn how to access the Fingerprint scanner on my Galaxy S5 via Android programming.
I am finding little to no information on the web or even the developers sites.

What I want to do is to create a simple app that uses the fingerprint scanner as a means to verify who is using the app or give permission to open the app as a sort of verification before opening.  Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: Getting [Samsung's SDK](http://developer.samsung.com/galaxy#pass) would probably be a good start.

Comment: @Michael  thats the answer man! (So post it.)  Maybe also add a link to the sample project here : http://developer.samsung.com/resources/pass#

Answer (score 0):

Most vendors have their own SDKs available.

Here is Samsung's, called Pass: http://developer.samsung.com/galaxy#pass